# How to create database in mongodb with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, flask, pymongo

I am making an API with Flask and MongoDB.

But when I add a data to the API it automatically creates a database with name test how to avoid that.
I need to use the database I created.

My code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine

db = MongoEngine()
app = Flask(__name__)
db.init_app(app)


app.config['MONGODB_SETTINGS'] = {
    'host': "mongodb+srv://Python:<password>@pandemic-healer-v2.lbuix.mongodb.net"
}


class Users(db.Document):
    email = StringField(required=True, unique=True)
    password = StringField(required=True)


@app.route('/sign', methods=['POST'])
def sign():
    body = request.get_json()
    user = Users(**body).save()
    mail = user.email
    return {'email': mail}, 200
```

I need the database name to be "Data" but it is created as "test" automatically.

[image]
Please give me a solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the database name by setting the `db` argument in your `MONGODB_SETTINGS`

```
app.config['MONGODB_SETTINGS'] = {
    'db': 'Data',
    'host': "mongodb+srv://Python:<password>@pandemic-healer-v2.lbuix.mongodb.net"
}
```

Comment: Create the database first using the `+ Create Database` button from the interface then you can access it from your code.